# Error when executing testng.xml using pagefactory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

I am running 2 classes using testNG.First class is running successfully but second class is failing with error:

> "org.testng.TestNGException:Can't invoke public void TestScripts.NewAccountCreation.AccountCreation1(): either make it static or add a no-args constructor to your class"

If I add non argument constructor I am getting null pointer exception.

I am using Pagefactory to design my test cases.

Eclipse version:kepler

TestnG:6.9.9

Chrome version: 57.0.2987.133

Chrome driver: 2.27

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Please find the below code:**

**Page factory Code for Login Page:**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import Pages.LoginPage;

public class LoginPage {

    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver ldriver)

    {
        this.driver = ldriver;

    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@id,'username-inputEl')]")
    public WebElement username;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@id,'password-inputEl')]")
    public WebElement password;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(@id,'submit-btnInnerEl')]")
    public WebElement LoginButton;

    // Methods to perform actions

    public void pCLogin(String Username, String Password, WebDriver driver)

    {

        username.sendKeys(Username);

        password.sendKeys(Password);

        LoginButton.click();

    }

}
```

**Page Factory code for Account creation page:**

```
package Pages;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Accounttab {

    WebDriver driver;

    public Accounttab(WebDriver ldriver)

    {
        this.driver = ldriver;

    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@id='TabBar:AccountTab-btnWrap']")
    public WebElement accountDropDown;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(@id,'AccountTab_NewAccount-textEl')]")
    public WebElement NewAccount_Button;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//textarea[contains(@id,'GlobalContactNameInputSet:Name-inputEl')]")
    public WebElement Companyname;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@id,'OfficialIDDV_Input-inputEl')]")
    public WebElement FEINNumber;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@id,'GlobalAddressInputSet:City-inputEl')]")
    public WebElement City;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[contains(@id,'GlobalAddressInputSet:PostalCode-inputEl')]")
    public WebElement Zipcode;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(@id,'SearchLinksInputSet:Search')]")
    public WebElement AccountsearchButton;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//span[@class='x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center'][contains(@id,'NewAccountButton-btnInnerEl')]")
    public WebElement CreateNewButton;

    @FindBy(css = "input[id='TabBar:AccountTab:AccountTab_AccountNumberSearchItem-inputEl']")
    public WebElement AccountSearch;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//tbody[contains(@id,'gridview')]//tr[1]//td[2]")
    public WebElement SelectAccountNumber;



    public void accountMouseHover(WebDriver driver) {

        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(accountDropDown));

        Actions builder2 = new Actions(driver);

        builder2.moveToElement(accountDropDown).moveByOffset(50, 0).click()
                .build().perform();

        System.out.println("Dropdown is opened");

    }

    public void accountSearch(String AccountName, WebDriver driver)

    {


        WebDriverWait  wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

         wait.until(ExpectedConditions .visibilityOf(NewAccount_Button));


        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);

        builder1.moveToElement(NewAccount_Button).click().build().perform();

        System.out.println("Clicked on New Accounr Button");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Companyname.sendKeys(AccountName);

        try {

            AccountsearchButton.click();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Please enter one of the minimum required fields: Company Name, FEIN"
                            + e);
            throw (e);
        }


         wait.until(ExpectedConditions .visibilityOf(CreateNewButton));

        CreateNewButton.click();

    }

  }
```

**Test Scripts1:
LoginClass:**

**

```
package TestScripts;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Pages.LoginPage;
import Utility.Configreader;
import Utility.GenericMethods;

public class Login {

     WebDriver driver;

    LoginPage Login_page;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() {

        Configreader cr = new Configreader(
                "H://Selenium//Selenium_ODSRegression//TestData//config.properties");

        driver = GenericMethods.startBrowser("Chrome", cr.getURL());

        Login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void PClogin() {

        Login_page.pCLogin("su", "gw", driver);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

}
```

**

**Test Script2: 
AccountCreation class:**

```
package TestScripts;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Pages.AccountFileSummary;
import Pages.Accounttab;
import Pages.CreateNewAccount;

public class NewAccountCreation {

    WebDriver driver;

    Accounttab Account_tab1;

    CreateNewAccount NewAccount1;

    AccountFileSummary AFS1;

    public NewAccountCreation(WebDriver ldriver)

    {
        this.driver = ldriver;

        Account_tab1 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Accounttab.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void AccountCreation1() {

        Account_tab1.accountMouseHover(driver);

        Account_tab1.accountSearch("WebDriver_Test1", driver);

    }

}
```

**driver class:**

```js
package Utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import Utility.Configreader;

public class GenericMethods {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    static Configreader cr = new Configreader(
            "H://Selenium//Selenium_ODSRegression//TestData//config.properties");

    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browsername, String URL)

    {
        if (browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))

        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    cr.getChromeDriverPath());

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
            options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
            options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
            options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        else if (browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))

        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", cr.getIEDriverPath());

            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

        driver.get(URL);

        return driver;

    }

}
```

**Property file:**

```
PCURL = http://biltipolicycenter.thehartford.com/pc/PolicyCenter.do
ChromeBrowserPath = C://Selenium//ChromeDriver 2.27//chromedriver.exe
IEBrowserPath = C://Selenium//IEDriverServer x86 2.53//IEDriverServer.exe
```

**TestNG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestScripts.Login"/>
      <class name="TestScripts.NewAccountCreation"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: Why are you creating the driver variable in different classes. Just use the public static variable you have in the GenericsMethod class. Not an ideal solution though as in parallel mode you might get weird behaviour.

Comment: @Grasshopper - I tried doing the same..using static driver variable i all my classes but I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running multiple classes in TestNG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474568/running-multiple-classes-in-testng)

Answer (score 0):

`NewAccountCreation` is a test class because it contains test method(s) and because you declare it as a class test in the `testng.xml`.

So, it means TestNG must be able to create an instance of the class and that's why TestNG is complaining.

You have 2 options:

1. Using [a factory](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) to explain to TestNG how to create test classes
   (best option IMO)
2. Using a static shared driver instance (`Login#driver` is not
   yet static)

BTW, your organization of classes looks a bit dirty and you should rework them a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Can you please tell me how to make my Login#driver as static.

Comment: `public static WebDriver driver;`

Comment: Thank you.It worked. can you tell me what wrong with organisation of my classes.I am new to coding.

Comment: You should have a look at the Page Object pattern. For example: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects